# Block direct access to directory with .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, directory

How I can block the direct access to my directory images?
I was trying this:

```
deny from all
```

But this block the images inside the folder too, so, the images doesn't appear in site.
How I can block only the direct access to directory? For example, the Google, if you try access the URL of the image, you can, but if you try to see the directory that contains all images, he gives a 404 error.
I hope that you understood my problem and help me.
Thanks!

Comment: are you looking to deny directory listing, if so add "Options -Indexes" to your htaccess

Comment: ok i will post that as a answer

Answer (score 3):

to prevent directory listing, use the following directive:

```
Options -Indexes
```